# When does IIndex<K,V> instanciates its resolved components?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I searched about topics related to this question, but I didnt find the answer i was looking for.
Sorry in advance if this has already been said.

Let's present my question :
I've a concrete class, let's call it BLLClass, on which I inject by constructor two implementations of IRepository.
Each of thoses implementations has its own DbContext type.
I want to have access to both IRepository at anytime, to be able to perform actions on any database at anytime, and to dispose them once i've finished.
Originally, I went with something like that :

```cs
public BLLClass : IDisposable
{
    private Dictionary<eBaseSQL,IRepository<SomeObjectType>> Repositories;

    public BLLClass(IIndex<eBaseSql, IRepository<SomeObjectType> repositories)
    {
        Repositories = new Dictionary<eBaseSQL, IRepository<SomeObjectType>>();
        Repositories.Add(eBaseSQL.DatabaseOne, repositories[eBaseSQL.DatabaseOne]);
        Repositories.Add(eBaseSQL.DatabaseTwo, repositories[eBaseSQL.DatabaseTwo]);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach(IRepository<SomeObjectType> Repository in Repositories.Values)
        {
            Repository.Dispose();
        }   
    }
}
```

This is working fine and doing exactly what I want.
But, I find it kinda ugly to add my implementations into a Dictionary while Autofac provides IIndex, which, is not a dictionary but LOOKS LIKE to act like one.

So here's my questions :
Can i use IIndex like I do with Dictionary ?
When does my concrete implementation of IRepository gets instanciated ?
Will it create a new object eachtime I do

```cs
// Let's say that "repositories" is a IIndex<K,V>
IRepository<SomeObjectType> someRepository = repositories[someEnum.SomeValue];
```

Or it will give always the same object ?
This really concerns me because, if IIndex instanciates a new Repository everytime I use one, I won't be able to dispose them afterwards.

Thanks for your time, and sorry for my english that is clearly, not the best.

Comment: Have a look at [Named and Keyed Services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)

Comment: Hello, I've looked at them. I think what I needed more was the Instance Scope page. I'm still beginner so I get lost sometimes.
Thanks anyway, Olivier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The injected `IIndex` does act like a factory, as you say. With

```
// Let's say that "repositories" is a IIndex<K,V>
IRepository<SomeObjectType> someRepository = repositories[someEnum.SomeValue];
```

That will return either a new or existing object, depending on how everything has been registered. By default, you would get a new object every time `repositories[someEnum.SomeValue]` is called.

Regarding disposal, I think you can leverage one of several built-in Autofac options to get the behaviour you want, if you switch your `Repositories` field to this:

```
public BLLClass : IDisposable
{
    private IIndex<eBaseSQL,IRepository<SomeObjectType>> Repositories;
```

First question: is it important to have the same repo of each type for all operations which the `BLLClass` executes in its lifetime? The overhead creating objects such as your repos each time they're used is generally pretty small, and using shorter-lived objects can help keep things simple and clean. In that case, if your registrations for the repos are `InstancePerDependency` (this is also the default), in your `BLLClass`, operations would just look like:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    using (var repo = Repositories[eBaseSql.SomeKey])
    {
    }
}
```

So the repo would be recreated every time you request it and you can safely dispose of each instance yourself with `using`. That would still work resolving the repos multiple times, like:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    using (var repo = Repositories[eBaseSql.SomeKey]) { }
    using (var sameRepoAgainButNew = Repositories[eBaseSql.SomeKey]) { }
}
```

The other approach, if you do need a single instance of each repo for any calls within the lifetime of a single `BLLClass`, you can just register your `IRepository` implementation using Autofac's `.InstancePerLifetimeScope`:

```
builder.RegisterType<Repository<SomeObjectType>>()
    .Keyed<IRepository<SomeObjectType>>(eBaseSql.SomeKey)
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Then if in `BLLClass` you have:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    var repo = Repositories[eBaseSql.SomeKey];
}
```

that repo instance should be disposed at the end of the life of the BLLClass. The assumption is that the BLLClass itself created from a scope which is disposed one way or another, a very simple example being:

```
using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var bll = scope.Resolve<BLLClass>();
    bll.DoStuff();
}
```

The implementation of `IIndex<>` which is injected into the `BLLClass` stores a reference to a component context which is disposed when that outer scope is disposed, which in turn will dispose of any child objects which implement IDisposable (see https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#automatic-disposal). In this case, that's the repositories we've generated. For example:

```
using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var bll = scope.Resolve<BLLClass>();
    bll.DoStuff();      // do something using our first repo implementation
    bll.DoMoreStuff();  // do something else using the same type of repo
}                       // here the scope is disposed, taking any generated repos with it

public void DoStuff()
{
    var repo = _repositories[eBaseSql.SomeKey];
    // some actions here
}

public void DoMoreStuff()
{
    var repo = _repositories[eBaseSql.SomeKey];    // the same repo as used in DoStuff will be returned here because of the .InstancePerLifetimeScope registration
}
```

Dynamically creating objects with one of these approaches using Autofac's built-in factories also means that you won't create any repos you end up not using, which looks to be possible in your initial implementation.

Comment: First thanks John King for your answer. It must have took you some times to make it.
You totally covered everything my questions implied.
I don't need to have the same repo during the whole life time of BLLClass.
I think i'll go for ".InstancePerDependency()" with using statement because then my BLLClass doesnt need to implement IDisposable.
I'm having trouble figuring out when using ".InstancePerLifeTimeScope()" would be preferable, but my problem is solved ! Thanks again (I did upvote your answer but my rep is too low to display it)

Comment: No worries. I think you can still accept the answer as per this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (I'm also new to this). Thanks!